# DataCore список пользователей

Tags: ios, swift, coredata

Ребята, подскажите, как дополнить мою программу, чтобы пользователю, например, User1 соответствовал добавленный asset1, а, например, User2 соответствовал asset2. Естественно с сохранением в Core Data программы.

Архив с программой приложил по ссылке ниже. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

[Скачать архив с проектом](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzb0kH6fcSmDODhJdU9JTkExX3c/view?usp=sharing)

**Файл класса User:**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


class User: NSManagedObject
{

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var asset: NSSet?

}
```

**Файл класса AddUser:**

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData

 class AddUser: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
 {

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 var users = [User]()

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let manageContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")

    do
    {
        let fetchResult = try manageContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        users = fetchResult as! [User]
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
        return
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return users.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = users[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

func addFunc(name: String)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let manageContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: manageContext)
    let user = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: manageContext) as! User
    user.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

    do
    {
        try manageContext.save()
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    users.append(user)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func addUser(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Новый сотрудник", message: "Введите ммя сотрудника", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Сохранить", style: .Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0]
        self.addFunc(textField.text!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler ({(textField: UITextField) -> Void in })
    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Сохранить", style: .Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in })
    alert.addAction(okButton)
    alert.addAction(cancelButton)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

**Файл класса Asset:**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


class Asset: NSManagedObject
{

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var user: User?

}
```

**Файл класса AddAsset:**

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData

 class AddAssets: UIViewController
 {

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 var assets = [Asset]()

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) 
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let manageContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Asset")

    do
    {
        let fetchResult = try manageContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        assets = fetchResult as! [Asset]
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
        return
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return assets.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("assetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = assets[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

func addFunc(name: String)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let manageContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Asset", inManagedObjectContext: manageContext)
    let asset = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: manageContext) as! Asset
    asset.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

    do
    {
        try manageContext.save()
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    assets.append(asset)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func addUser(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Новое оборудование", message: "Введите имя оборудования", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Сохранить", style: .Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0]
        self.addFunc(textField.text!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler ({(textField: UITextField) -> Void in })
    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Сохранить", style: .Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in })
    alert.addAction(okButton)
    alert.addAction(cancelButton)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

**CoreData model выглядит так:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с какой целью вы выложили архив? Покажите код, который по вашему может быть с проблемой.

Comment: Добавил развёрнутое описание проекта!

Comment: а что уже пробовали?

Comment: Есть мысли через промежуточную сущность фильтровать

Comment: у вас по моему relation должен быть one-to-one а не one-to-many

Comment: Так тоже не работает

В общем, ещё раз объясню,  что хочется получить:
Нужно чтобы asset 1 соответствовал User1, а User2 не видел asset1, а сейчас получается что все пользователи видят весь список asset-ов

Comment: Ладно, убирайте весь код. оставьте только код, который вновь созданному ассету присваивает юзера. Давайте от этого отталкиваться.

Comment: Что-то я совсем запутался. Ответ где-то совсем на поверхности и очень очевиден, у меня получаются совсем замысловатые конструкции, которые, на мой взгляд не должны быть такими сложными для такой простой схемы. Прошу помощи у знатоков. Напишите пример, пожалуйста. Сил уже нет...

Comment: пробуем еще раз: у вас отсутствует большой кусок бизнес логики. 1) при создании asset ему не назначается user. 2) контроллер который создает asset понятия сам не имеет для какого user это делается.